# Modification in the code to classify it into less than 100 classes

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am dealing with a classification problem. The following code only works when I divide my data into 100 classes. If I divide my data into less than 100 classes it gives me error that the index is out of bound.My training labels are 85000 and test labels are 15000 Can some one please tell me that it is giving this error and how to fix it?

```
def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes):
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    index_offset = numpy.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    labels_one_hot = numpy.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    return labels_one_hot

def extract_labels(labels,num_classes, one_hot=False):
    if one_hot :
        return dense_to_one_hot(labels,num_classes)
    return labels
```

Comment: please add the exact error message (with stack trace).

Comment: labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1,    Indexerror: index 4750027 is out of bound for size 4750000

Comment: Here is my error. 4750027 is the number of samples that I want to train. When I change the number of classes in which I want to divide my data then I get this error.